# Trouble getting object in Django's models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a user submission form, and the user supplies his name and email. Each email is associated to a network (by an admin, prior to user registration), and based upon a user's email he will be assigned to that network.

Here is what the models.py looks like --

```
class Network(models.Model):
    network = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class EmailList(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    network = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    network = models.ForeignKey(Network)
```

And in the `views.py` this is what I am using to try and insert the record into the database --

```
User.objects.create(
name = cd['name']
email=cd['email'],
network= EmailList.objects.filter(email=request.POST.get('email'))['network'])
```

However, I am getting an exception TypeError from the `network=` line. What should the syntax be here to 'pull' and insert the network associated with the email into the database? What am I doing incorrectly

**Update**

Here is the code I used in `views.py` to get it working.

```
email_list = EmailList.objects.get(email=cd['email'])
network= Network.objects.get(network=email_list.network)
User.objects.create(
    name=cd['name'], 
    email=cd['email'], 
    network=network)
```

When I tried setting the variable `email = cd['email']` and then defining the email_list using that variable like so --  `email_list = EmailList.objects.get(email=email)`, it would raise an exception saying Queryset not found in EmailList and would pass a unicode string.

Why does defining the variable before passing it in this case create a unicode string, whereas passing the expression directly in does not?

Comment: `email` in `EmailList` should be something like `user` as a foreign key to `User`, and `network` should be a foreign key to `Network` instead of a `CharField`. You'll save yourself a ton of look up headaches that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once again, you shouldn't be using the post data directly.

Filter returns a queryset not an instance. That looks like what is causing your problem.
Also you need to get a network instance instead of a string to set to User.network:

if email for EmailList and network for Network models are unique you can do the following, if not and there are multiple entries using get will raise an Error.

```
name = cd.get('name')
email = cd.get('email')
email_list = EmailList.objects.get(email=email)
network = Network.objects.get(network=email_list.network)

User.object.create(name=name, email=email, network=network)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now, it appears that the logic is working, but I am getting an error that says EmailList does not exist matching query. However, when I look at the database, the email that I am specifying does in fact exist, and both the network and email entries are unique. Also, should I be adding a foreign key to the 'network' column in the EmailList class model?

Comment: That makes sense because your email list has a many to one relationship with networks. You can have many emails associated with a single network. Also it saves you a look up for to get your network object because you could then get your email list object and use the fk directly when creating your user object.